# Calculate required position to keep object centered when camera is rotated

Tags: unity, c#

I always want to keep an object in the center of view of a camera.
When the camera's rotation X value is -45, the object should still be centered.

Therefore I need to calculate the new position of the camera.

How could the "required camera position Y value" be calculated?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Track the object we want to keep centered.
public transform centeredObject;

void LateUpdate() {
    // Cache how far we are from the object before we do anything to the camera.
    // (This could instead be a constant distance you've set via an Inspector variable)
    float cameraDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, centeredObject.position);

    // Apply whatever change you want to make to the camera's orientation.
    transform.rotation = ComputeNewCameraRotation();    

    // Calculate its new position by "backing up" the desired distance
    // from your centered object, along the camera's new look direction.
    transform.position = centeredObject.position - cameraDistance * transform.forward;
}
```